# Develop apps for Ubuntu touch: Learning by doing

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, c++, qml

I really want to develop apps for Ubuntu touch. I have set up the Ubunut sdk and i am currently reading tutorials about qml but one will not learn programming by reading books or tutorials so i am looking for like little tasks (with solutions), which focus on QML and Ubuntu touch.You don't get alot of information about how Ubuntu touch works and how you combine the different languages. Is there any way, which makes the start easier? I really need an overview of how the whole thing works and finally start doing something.